# White space in front of ul

Tags: html, css, removing-whitespace

I have an unordered list and is displayed inlined but the problem is that in front of the list appears some white space like in the following image :

[image: SpaceInfront]

This is the css :

```
#ul-right{
  float:right;        
}

.li-right{
  display:inline;
  font-size:initial;
}

.ul-leftright{
  font-size: 0px;    
}
```

and this is the html :

```
<ul id="ul-right" class="ul-leftright">
  <li class="li-right">
    <a runat="server" href="Login.aspx">Login</a>
  </li>
  <li class="li-right">
    <a runat="server" href="LogOut.aspx">Logout</a>
  </li>
  <li class="li-right">
    <a runat="server" href="Register.aspx">Register</a>
  </li>
  <li class="li-right">
    <a runat="server" href="~/Cart/MyCart.aspx">MyCart</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Can you please me tell me why is this happening and can you help me remove the white space ?

Comment: Most elements have some default padding and margin. Remove it.

Comment: you may do a reset for paddings and margins to ul and / or li

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's the default padding on the `ul` element. Most browsers add a `padding-left` value of ~ `40px`.

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/JP9D5/)

```
ul {
    padding: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try  using

```
ul {
    padding: 0;
    margin:0;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/kK85g/)

Some elements have some default padding and margin.

Comment: @StefanP. you are welcome..and happy to help :)